# What are the atributes of a Pativrata woman?

Tags: marriage, wife

Pativrata wife is revered very highly in Hinduism. As she not only protects the husband from death and other bad events but also guarantees the husband heaven.(correct me if I am wrong).

So, what are the attributes of a Pativrata wife ?
I don't think being chaste should be the only criteria for being a Pativrata . As many women are chaste but they are obviously not Pativrata.